# Why is an "indexed set" indeed a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

Let $ S = \{S_{i}:i \in I \} $. If $I$ is a set, and for every $ i \in I$, $S_{i}$ is a set. Why does it imply that $S$ must be a set? I have been thinking about this for a while but it's like a loop. I always come to the same point, and nothing is really proven.
I do not from where, but I recall that if $f:A \longrightarrow B$ is a surjective function, and $A$ is a set, then $B$ must be a set. Is it helpful here? And if so, what is needed in order to prove it?

Comment: What axiom system are you using? In ZF this can be proved using the axiom of [replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) for example.

Comment: Using the axiom of replacement assumes you have a formula $\phi$ such that $\phi(i,S_i)$, which is reasonable if you've defined $S_i$ in terms of $i$. However, you can set up situations where the set theory is unaware of the indexing. This is easy to see when constructing a model of ZFA with ur-elements $a_i | i \in \omega$; one has the choice as to whether $\{a_i | i \in \omega\}$ is in the model or not.

Comment: @TomKern: How is that different from a countable model of any set theory, where you enumerate the model? Or have a generic new subset of $\omega$? Etc.

Comment: Is not an indexed set a function from $\mathbb N$ or from a subset of $\mathbb N$ to a family of sets $S$? If it is a function, it is a set. My comment amounts to saying that an indexed set is a set in the same way as a sequence is a set.

Comment: @VinceVickler - Indices do not necessarily have to come from a subset of $\Bbb N$. $I$ could be anything. But other than that, what you say is correct. Before you can talk about an "indexed set", you have to define what that means, and the usual definition requires $S$ to be a set. However, this is so obvious that blargoner and TomKern are interpreting the indexing as arising from some logical formula on the elements of $I$ rather than a function.